# Coating a soldered connection on a small circuit board

Tags: soldering, solder-mask, conformal-coating

I have a small PCB, about the size of a quarter and having a Bluetooth chip on it. I have 4 wires soldered to the board. 2 of which are for a 3.7 Volt battery connection and 2 are to connect a small loudspeaker.

All of my components (PCB, battery, loudspeaker) are going to be encased in a cloth band and worn on a persons ankle. I am worried that through repetitive movement, my soldered connections will get disconnected.

Is there a recommendation for further protecting the soldered connections. I feel like wrapping it in electric tape won't be enough. Is there some kind of latex coating I can use to either coat the soldered connections or even the entire board?

I've heard of conformal coating. Is that my solution? If so which type for my case?

Comment: Instead of using a conformal coating, I'd encapsulate it using a soft urethane or [silicone](http://www.masterbond.com/products/two-part-silicone-adhesives-sealants-and-coatings) encapsulant, and for the wires I'd use something like [this](http://www.daburn.com/2671UltraFlexibleSub-MiniatureWire-U/LSTYLE15681692.aspx?gclid=CLyohNHUn8QCFVKAaQod1VEANA) and strain-relieve them where they exit the pooky.

Comment: How about putting the whole thing inside heat-shrink sleeving?

Comment: Both are great options. The heat-shrink sleeve sounds less messy. Where can I find sleeves of different sizes? Mine needs to be about 3cm in width.

Comment: @EMFields do you think I can encapsulate the entire PCB (except for the on/off switch on the side of the PCB of course)?

Comment: @Majenko any thoughts on where to find heat shrink sleeves for PCBs?

Comment: Any electronics supplier should stock them if your PCB is small enough. Sleeving comes in sizes that would surprise you.  Inches wide some of it...

Comment: shrink sleeving found @ digikey
http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/us/en/3m-heatshrink-cable-sleeves/1258

Comment: exactly my thoughts regarding the shrink warp +1 to majenko :)

Comment: Auto stores have the 1 inch flat tube

Comment: You could combine the two ideas by using heat shrink tubing that has a hot glue coating inside.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that hot-melt glue makes a great board coating.  Cheap, very easy to use, no solvents involved, sets up in minutes instead of days, excellent electricals.

Comment: If rework is needed it's also very easy to remove using denatured alcohol.  Just swab the area with 90+% alcohol, wait a minute or two and the glue peels right off.  It's otherwise nigh impossible to remove.